# Algolia Wordpress plugin not indexing post content

Tags: wordpress, search, algolia

Just wondering if you guys could help me. I have indexed all my content from WP and when using the instant search only a few posts are showing any sort of excerpt. I have reindexed a few times to see if it resolved it to no luck.

I am looking on algolia's dashboard and when searching for specific items they have only specific attributes filled in. [screenshot from algolia dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzqnI.png)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

By default the plugin will split the post's content into multiple Algolia records.

Then when displaying results, we display the most relevant matched record as the excerpt.

You could customize this behaviour by following this guide: https://community.algolia.com/wordpress/customize-search-page.html

Let us know if there is something you would like to achieve that does not seem supported or easy to implement.

**Update:**

It seems like some users are more satisfied with putting the `post_title` as last in the ranking. That way, the displayed excerpt will be relevant.
the only cases where this would not be ideal is if you want the post title to be more important as the content of your post.

Comment: Hi @rayrutjes. I have tried changing the ranking but the only way I am able to see any posts with content is by deleting multiple records inside algolias dashboard. Customising the search page doesn't work as not all fields are returned. Even in the algolia dashboard when testing the searches I am only seeing the same fields. The title1, 2, 3 etc never shows me any different

Comment: I just updated the answer to add an alternative suggestion.